# RSA encryption using SecKeyEncrypt getting Error at server side while Decryption after Upgrading iOS 9.3 to iOS 10.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, rsa

I am using RSA Encryption using SecKeyEncrypt I am able to encrypt my data but encrypted data not able to parse from server side.
It is working fine with iOS 9.3 OS devices.
After updating from iOS 9.3 to 10 the issue is coming.
The issue is device specific not XCode specific I check the same with XCode 8 and earlier XCode 7.3.

```
 SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
SecTrustRef myTrust;
SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(myCertificate, myPolicy, &myTrust);
SecKeyRef publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(myTrust);
NSData *dataSymmetricKey = [strCreateXmlForKey `
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const void *bytesSymmetricKey = [dataSymmetricKey bytes];


uint8_t *symmetricKeyText = (uint8_t*)bytesSymmetricKey;
uint8_t symmetricCipherText[1024];
size_t  symmetricCipherLength = 1024;


NSString *EncryptedString=[self encryptWithData:dataSymmetricKey publicKey:publicKey];


SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey,
              kSecPaddingPKCS1,
              symmetricKeyText,
              strlen( (char*)symmetricKeyText ) + 1,
              symmetricCipherText,
              &symmetricCipherLength);
```

Comment: anyone have idea about this